# arrays.aslist adding derived class java

Tags: java, arrays, list, version

So I have this:

```
class A{}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {
    public String toString(){ return new String("C"); } 
    }
class D extends B {
    public String toString(){ return "D"; } 
    }
```

And then in main

```
List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new C(), new D());
        for (A a : list) {
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        }
```

I can compile this code and it prints:
C
D 
but on my friend's computer it won't compile. 
It has to deal with the Java version I am using ?

Comment: what is the error..?

Comment: Well i don't know what error my friend got, he just told me that it doesn't compile. I was curious why my code worked on my computer while on my friend's computer didn't. Meanwhile I have found my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right. You must be compiling on Java 8 while your friend is on Java 7.

In Java 7, the type of of the `List` returned by

```
Arrays.asList(new C(), new D());
```

would be inferred as `List<B>` and [a `List<B>` cannot be assigned to a `List<A>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

In Java 8, with some smarter generics, the compiler would infer a different type for the same expression, `List<A>`.

You can correct the Java 7 version with an explicit type argument

```
Arrays.<A>asList(new C(), new D());
```

Comment: Thanks! My OOP professor told us in course that it doesn't compile and i was surprised to see that on my computer it compiled.